# run python with crontab with string dates as arguments

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script, which works when I run:

```
python my_script.py --start_time 2020-09-18-09-00 --end_time 2020-09-18-19-00 >> log_file.log 2>&1
```

I am trying to run in crontab:

```
14 16 * * * python my_script.py --start_time 2020-09-18-09-00 --end_time 2020-09-18-19-00 >> log_file.log 2>&1
```

but it fails - It says that I have a SyntaxError in the python script (which didn`t happen while I ran the python script without crontab).

I guess that I have a mistake in the syntax of the crontab command.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: it is likely that your python version is different from the python in system default path. please provide the output of `python --version` and `whereis python`

Comment: modify and use full path (use the real locations): `14 16 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to_my_script/my_script.py --start_time 2020-09-18-09-00 --end_time 2020-09-18-19-00 >> log_file.log 2>&1
`

Comment: also read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176226/passing-a-command-with-arguments-to-a-script . make sure your argument is read correctly in the python script launched by crontab by printing it out.

Comment: It works! thanks!! can you add this as an answer and I will accept it? such that it will help others as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

my python version was different from the python in system default path.

for example, if the relevant python version for this script is `/usr/bin/python`, you have to modify the command to be:

```
14 16 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to_my_script/my_script.py --start_time 2020-09-18-09-00 --end_time 2020-09-18-19-00 >> log_file.log 2>&1
```